# How to transfer weights between vertex groups on separate meshes

Tags: mesh, particles, vertex-groups

I got 2 objects, 1 has all the vertex groups from the rigged armature, the other doesnt have those, but it has all of the weight paint vertex groups for hair length and density on it.

Object 1 did have these weights for hair, but were overwritten when parenting the mesh to the armature and doing "Automatic Weights" so i lost them and my hair is messed up. luckly i got a backup with those weights, problem is, i cant find a way to transfer those vertex groups from mesh 2 to mesh 1 without overwritting the already existing groups of mesh 1.
its there a way to transfer these WITHOUT overwritting the others?

Answer (score 2):

am dum dum and found the answer like 10 min later.

Answer was to use a Data Transfer modifier on the mesh, have both Backup Mesh and OG Mesh in the exact same position, then enable Vertex trasnfer thingy, select the mesh you wanna transfer weights to in my case "UwU -> Nyaa"
(apologies for custom theme, hopefully its understandable)
[image]

this means whatever weights are on the "UwU" vertex group will be transfered over the "Nyaa" group. now the reason they need to be exactly positioned is because its more of a weight projection transfer rather than a seamless transfer.

Another useful and more practical method (suggested by moonboots in the comments, thanks!) is to use the "Transfer Mesh Data" tool, easiest way is to Search "Transfer Mesh Data" and once you click on it you will see similar settings than the modifier.
[image]
For transfering vertex groups make sure the active groups on both meshes are the ones you wanna transfer, way it works is transfering Active object's weight over to selected.

Comment: could you please make a screenshot of the modifier so that we know exactly what options you've enabled? Also, you could have used the Object > Relations > Mesh Data Transfer tool, but same thing I'm not sure about the right settings

Comment: oh.. well its basically the same thing but with a modifier instead of an operation, works kinda the same, annnnd! updated