# Add/Transfer one object's weight painted vertex groups to different object (identical mesh)?

Tags: weight-painting

I have two versions of a face mesh (via <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>--should be identical XYZ positions); one has correct eye (and nose) weight-painting and the other has correct lips (and chin) weight-painting. The only vertex group they both share is "head", since each object's specific region's weights were subtracted from the head. Is it possible to add/transfer one object's VGs (e.g. lips) to the other (e.g. eyes) and also correctly combine (subtract) the relevant weights from the overlapping VG (e.g. head)? I tried applying the commenter's answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/175389/how-to-transfer-weights-between-vertex-groups-on-separate-meshes) (TL;DR: Data Transfer modifier), but got strange midline-lips and lateral inner-mouth motion. (The inner mouth is not shown.) Thanks!

Face with correct eyes rig (JP names are "head" and "eyelash top/bottom 1, 2, etc."):

[image]

Lips (masked from identical face mesh) with correct lips rig (JP names are "head" and "(center)top/bottom lip L/R):

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using ALT-d instead?

Comment: No explanation in comment, so I had to look it up (https://blenderartists.org/t/difference-between-shift-d-and-alt-d/603153). Looks like Alt+D would've had to be something I did BEFORE weighting the lips (I'd used Shift+D)... Any way to retroactively add the lips weights/VGs to the rest of the face, or do I have to manually rerig?

Comment: Comments are for asking the OP questions.
Using ALT-d will copy the mesh with all its weight painting intact, then you can break the link after copying. If you'd like more detail I can put it as an answer.

Comment: @Psyonic Shift+D OR Alt+D -> joining (Ctrl+J) the working halves of the face both seem to work. It's possible I'm not using Alt+D the way you imagine, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a more streamlined way.

The nose rig didn't change between the eyes-rig and lips-rig face objects, so I duplicated them both -> deleted the nonfunctional halves of each mesh at the nose bridge -> merged (Ctrl+J) the functional halves. I also merged the same-loop/XYZ-coords edge loops  (Merge by Distance) and cleared sharp edges to resolve a subtle but obvious shading issue. Here, Shift+D and Alt+D didn't seem to differ as a duplication method.